# How to fork/background a subprocess without stalling the parent process

Tags: macos, bash, shell, zsh

I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite running a bash shell with zsh/oh-my-zsh.

So my goal is to create a function which grabs some information (if it exists) and return that information, then spawn off a child process that generates that info to be used next time.  The reason is that this function which generates the info is slow (2-5 seconds sometimes) and i dont want the parent shell to hang while this is being created.

I'm creating this function as a prompt decorator for a zsh-theme, so it would be *really* bad to hang this long every time it re-generated the prompt.  It's pretty much this solution (or any alternative no-hang solution) works, or the feature gets scrapped.

Right now i'm using the following code:

```
decorations=""
getDecs () {
    echo $decorations
    ( buildDecorationList & )
}

buildDecorationList () {
    local RetStr=""
    RetStr+=$(getList1) # Returns a list of stuff
    local temp=$(getList2) # Returns a second list of stuff
    if [[ $RetStr != "" && $temp != "" ]]; then
        RetStr+=", "
    fi
    RetStr+=$temp
    echo $RetStr # Return both lists concatenated
}
```

It's so close to working, and achieves most of what i want, in that it doesnt stall the main process and it correctly generates all of the info.  I'm just having trouble getting the output of this function properly directed back into the `decorations` variable in the main shell where it can be retrieved on the next function call.

I've tried various forms of redirection/variable assignment, but they always end up either a) not making it back to the main shell and/or being inaccessible or b) causing the parent function to hang while waiting for the output.

I've also looked into coprocesses, as they sounded promising at first but i'm not quite sure how they're different from subshells and they seem to have the same limitations for this particular use-case.  Or i'm not using them right.  Idk.

I also considered using an external file with a specific name, but that would get disastrously complex if the user ever decided to open more than one session...

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to put the result in a tmp file (using `mktmp`).
You create the tmp file in the main function, store it's reference in a global variable. So it can be access from the main and subfunction, and you can put logic in the main function not to relaunch the subprocess if variable is set.

You could eventually use a kind of `.lock` or `complete` file to signify process is done

```
decoration_file=""

getDecs () {
    if [ -z "$decoration_file" ] ; 
    then 
        decoration_file=`mktemp -t decoration`
       ( buildDecorationList & )
    elif [ ! -f "$decoration_file.complete" ]
          # non terminated, do the logic you want

    else
         cat $decoration_file
    fi

}

buildDecorationList () {
    local RetStr=""
    RetStr+=$(getList1) # Returns a list of stuff
    local temp=$(getList2) # Returns a second list of stuff
    if [[ $RetStr != "" && $temp != "" ]]; then
        RetStr+=", "
    fi
    RetStr+=$temp
    echo $RetStr > $decoration_file  # Return both lists concatenated
    touch ${decoration_file}.complete
}
```

You might adapt this is if the computation is to be done several time